# Using the reverse triangle inequality, $d(x,y) \geq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$, to show $M$ has at most one point.

Tags: general-topology, inequality, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Observe the following question:

> Let $M$ be a set and suppose that the metric (on $M$) $d : M \times M \to [0, \infty)$ satisfies properties $i)$ $0 \leq d(x,y) < \infty$ $\forall x,y \in M$, $ii)$ $d(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $x = y$, $iii)$ $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ $\forall x,y \in M$ and the triangle inequality reversed: $d(x,y) \geq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$. Show $M$ has *at most* one point.

**My Work:**

Suppose $M$ has an element greater than or equal to $2$. So, let $x,y \in M$ where $x \ne y$, therefore by $i)$ we know that $d(x,y) \geq 0$. Now by   property $ii)$ we know that $d(x,x) = 0$. So, using the triangle inequality reversed we compute: $$ \begin{align*} \ d(x,x) &\geq d(x,y) + d(y,x) \\ 0 &\geq 2d(x,y)  \\ 0 &\geq d(x,y) \end{align*}$$ Which we know to be a contradiction by property $i)$. Therefore $M$ has at most one point.

Is this correct?

---

**My Thoughts for improvement:**

$1)$ I feel like the first line "*Suppose $M$ has an element greater than or equal to $2$*..." is not needed, but my college disagrees. It feels more natural to start the proof with the second sentence.

$2)$ Are my inequalities correct? Is there anything that is redundant in the proof that could be made more precise or better worded?

$3)$ If there is an easier proof to this, please feel free to share.

Comment: $0\ge d(x,y)$ does not contradict property $i)$ at all, but, by using it, we get that $d(x,y)=0$. Moreover, by using the property $ii)$, it follows that $x=y$ which leads to a contradiction.

Comment: It would be better to write at the beginning that “We suppose that $M$ has two different elements”.

Comment: In my opinion there is not anything that is redundant in your proof, moreover I think there is not an easier proof.

Comment: @Angelo - Thank you for all your feedback. Would you mind composing an answer out of your comments that shows how using $ii)$ leads to a contradiction?

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $M$ has two different elements $x$ and $y$.

So $x,y \in M$ where $x \ne y$.

Now by property $ii)$ we know that $d(x,x) = 0$. So, using the triangle inequality reversed we compute: $$ \begin{align*} \ d(x,x) &\geq d(x,y) + d(y,x) \\ 0 &\geq 2d(x,y)  \\ 0 &\geq d(x,y) \end{align*}$$

Moreover, by property $i)$, we know that $d(x,y)\ge0$, so we get that $d(x,y)=0$ and, by applying property $ii)$, it follows that $x=y$, but it contradicts the fact that $x$ and $y$ are two different elements.

So it is impossible to get two different elements of $M$, otherwise it would lead to a contradiction.

Hence $M$ has at most one point.

Comment: Why by property $i)$ we yield $d(x,y) = 0$ when it is an inequality?

Comment: Everything else makes sense though.

Comment: Because the property $i)$ says that $d(x,y)\ge0$, but on the other hand we got that $d(x,y)\le0$, so there is only a possibility which is $d(x,y)=0$. In other words we applied the antisymmetric property of inequalities.

Comment: Gotcha, last question: the more I think about it, why are we allowed to use the reversed triangle inequality in this way: $d(x,x) \geq d(x,y) +d(y,x)$? Are we simply doing this to get a contradiction?

Comment: The reversed triangle inequality is valid for any $x$, $y$ and $z$ in $M$. So we are allowed to choose $y=x$ and the reversed triangle inequality $d(x,y) \geq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$ become $d(x,x)\ge d(x,z)+d(z,x)$. Then we can change the name of the element $z$ and call it $y$. So we get that $d(x,x)\ge d(x,y)+d(y,x)$